# How can I get all open graph pages owned by an application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get all open graph pages owned by an application.

I tried this query, but it returned an empty data set.  I want to try this with the app id instead and wondering if there is a way to do that.

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()&access_token={token}

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to get the pages owned by an application. But there is a way to get pages owned by a user:
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/accounts?access_token=ACESS_TOKEN

To perform this request user should allow access to your app with manage_pages privilege.